# The server encountered an error processing the request - the service does not exist

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Here is my server logs:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0
Date:          5/20/2015 9:25:51 AM
Event ID:      3
Task Category: WebHost
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5
Computer:      BC-MAS
Description:
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/54597678
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service '/Service1.svc' does not exist. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service '/Service1.svc' does not exist.
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 1428

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49154">3</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>5</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-20T06:25:51.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>4381</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>BC-MAS</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-82-271721585-897601226-2024613209-625570482-296978595" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/54597678</Data>
    <Data>System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service '/Service1.svc' does not exist. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service '/Service1.svc' does not exist.
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)</Data>
    <Data>w3wp</Data>
    <Data>1428</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I can't access the functions in my Service1, but first page is opening:
[image]
While when I'm trying to access one of the functions that returns data then error showing:
***The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.***
Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this problem was "ASP .NET 4.5 Application Pool" must be run 32-Bit programs so that this will make the service working normally.